# How do I characterize the distribution of the expected number of periods before the first success in a binomial distribution?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, convergence-divergence

I came across this statement in something at work:

> An exponential distribution of the length of up time would result from a model in which the probability of failure (down time) is constant through time.

I interpreted this as a binomial distribution where `0 = up` and `1 = down`, where the probability of a $1$ occurring is $0 < p < 1$. I realize this notation is a little backward, since we don't usually think of "up" as equating with "failure".

Now I'm trying to characterize the distribution of the length of time that a device is "up". Let $X$ be the discrete probability distribution of the length of the first up time. Then

\begin{align}
Pr(x = 0) &= p \\
Pr(x = 1) &= (1 - p) p \\
Pr(x = 2) &= (1 - p)^2 p \\
\ldots \\
Pr(x = n) &= (1 - p)^{n-1} p \\
\end{align}

Taking the expectation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (1 - p)^{n-1} p \\
&= p \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (1 - p)^{n-1} \\
&= \cfrac{p}{1-p} \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (1 - p)^{n} \\
\end{align}

Since
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \cfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert
&= \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \cfrac{(n+1)(1-p)^{n+1}}{n(1-p)^n} \right\rvert \\
&= (1 - p)\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \cfrac{(n+1)}{n} \right\rvert \\
&= (1 - p)\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert 1 + \cfrac{1}{n} \right\rvert \\
&= 1 - p \\
&< 1
\end{align}

I know the series converges by the Ratio Test. My problem is how to evaluate the infinite series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (1 - p)^{n}$, given that I know it converges, although I'm also unsure if I interpreted the initial statement correctly.

EDIT: In response to one of the comments about calculating the sum, is this a correct way to do so?

Let $S = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(1 - p)^n$. Then

\begin{align}
S - (1 - p)S &= \left( \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(1 - p)^n \right) - \left( (1 - p) \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(1 - p)^n \right) \\
pS &= (1 - p) + (1 - p)^2 + (1 - p)^3 + \cdots \\
pS &= \cfrac{1}{1 - (1 - p)} \\
\Rightarrow S &= \cfrac{1}{p^2} \end{align}

Comment: Your sum turns out to be $\frac{1}{p}-1$, the expectation of one version of the *geometric distribution* (please see Wikipedia) .  You can think of the geometric as a discretized version of the exponential (or the other way around, of the exponential as a continuous version of the geometric). Unfortunately, I don't know precisely what you are looking for apart from the summation.

Comment: To evaluate the series, you can name the sum A. Then multiply both sides of the equation by (1-P). Then subtract the two equation. you would have a geometric series and you can find A.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, the geometric distribution! I thought somewhere in the back of my mind that there was already a distribution characterizing this, but I couldn't place it.

Comment: If the distribution of time between successive events has exponential distribution, with the usual independence assumptions, then the number of events in time $t$ has *Poisson* distribution with parameteer $\lambda t$. That may be the kind of model you are looking for.

Comment: @Med Can you add more detail to that? Are you saying to do this?
\begin{align}
S - (1 - p)S &= \left( \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(1 - p)^n \right) - \left( (1 - p) \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(1 - p)^n \right) \\
pS &= (1 - p) + (1 - p)^2 + (1 - p)^3 + \cdots \\
pS &= \cfrac{1}{1 - (1 - p)} \\
\Rightarrow S &= \cfrac{1}{p^2}
\end{align}

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, I guess I'm just concerned with the sum at this point. Should that go in a new question, or should I cannibalize this question with an edit to make it focus completely on finding the sum?

Comment: Your $1/p^2$ looks right. But I do not understand your $E(X)$. You started to make a list $\Pr(x=0)$, $\Pr(x=1)$, $\Pr(x=2)$.  Presumably they are concrete enough to be what you intend. Thar would give $\Pr(x=n)=p(1-p)^n$, but you use exponent $n-1$ for some reason. I think when you put things together correctly you will get $E(X)=p(1-p)(1/p^2)$. This is the $\frac{1}{p}-1$ I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I was mixing up 1) the probability of $n$ trials occurring before the first success (so the first success occurs on the $n+1$ trial, and 2) the probability of the first success occurring on the $n$th trial. In case 1, $Pr(x = n) = (1 - p)^n p$, but in case 2), $Pr(x = n) = (1 - p)^{n-1} p$, correct?

Comment: There are two closely related distributions called geometric. In one of them, $X$ counts the number of **failures** until the first success. Then $X$ takes on values $0,1,2,\dots$, and $\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^k$. In the other version of the geometric, $X$ counts the number of **trials** up to and including the first success. Then $X$ takes on values $1,2,3,\dots$ and $\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$. Just tell me exactly what you want (it looks as if you want the first version of the geometric, but maybe not) and I will write an answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're correct; I had in mind the first version of the geometric distribution, so you can build an answer from that. I think I've figured it out, but for future reference for others, your answer would be a great help. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Since you summed the series, I thought I would add to your toolchest with a seriesless calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An experiment is repeated independently until the first success. Let random variable $X$ be the number of **failures** before the first success. If the probability of success on any trial is $p$, then for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ we have
$$\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^k.$$
It follows that 
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp(1-p)^k.\tag{1}$$
So we can evaluate $E(X)$ by finding a sum. Let us do it another way, by *conditioning* on the result of the first experiment.

Let $E(X)=a$. The result of the first trial is a success with probability $p$. The conditional expectation of $X$, given that the first trial yields success, is $0$.

With probability $1-p$, the result of the first trial is a failure. In that case, we have wasted a trial, and the expected number of *additional* trials until the first success is $a$, so the expected total number of trials is $1+a$. By the Law of Total Expectation, we have
$$a=(p)(0)+(1-p)(1+a).$$
Solve for $a$. We get, for $p\ne 0$, that 
$$a=\frac{1-p}{p}=\frac{1}{p}-1.$$

**Remark:** For fun we can now use the value of $a$ to find the sum $S$ of the series $1+2(1-p)+3(1-p)^2+\cdots$. For by Formula (1) we have
$a=p(1-p)S$, and therefore $S=\frac{a}{p(1-p)}=\frac{1}{p^2}$.